# e.target.value does not work for React input type=button

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux

Here is my input:

```
<input type="button" className="pull-right btn btn-info" style={{width: "33%"}} onClick={this.handleButtonChange.bind(this, marble._id)}
                                                       value="Assign"/>
```

And here is my event handler:

```
  handleButtonChange(marbleId, e) {
    var array = [...this.state.selectedMarbles]; // make a separate copy of the array
    var index = array.indexOf(marbleId);
      // append that element
    if(index<0) {
      array.push(marbleId);
      e.target.value="Unassign";
      e.target.classList.remove("btn-info");
      e.target.classList.add("btn-danger");
    } else {
      // remove that element
      array.splice(index, 1);
      e.target.value="Assign";
      e.target.classList.add("btn-info");
      e.target.classList.remove("btn-danger");
    }
    this.setState({selectedMarbles: array});
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

This changes the classes in the input tag but does not change the value.

However if I change above to button tag, it works as expected.

```
<button type="button" className="pull-right btn btn-info" style={{width: "33%"}} onClick={this.handleButtonChange.bind(this, marble._id)}
                >Select</button>
```

The event handler:

```
  handleButtonChange(marbleId, e) {
    var array = [...this.state.selectedMarbles]; // make a separate copy of the array
    var index = array.indexOf(marbleId);
      // append that element
    if(index<0) {
      array.push(marbleId);
      e.target.innerHTML="Selected";
      e.target.classList.remove("btn-info");
      e.target.classList.add("btn-danger");
    } else {
      // remove that element
      array.splice(index, 1);
      e.target.innerHTML="Select";
      e.target.classList.add("btn-info");
      e.target.classList.remove("btn-danger");
    }
    this.setState({selectedMarbles: array});
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

I wonder why is it happening like that.

Comment: Just a thought, I see no "value=x" in your second, working-example, and I do remember that props are `frozen` on render (and, "value", could be a prop).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are a lot of problems in your code...

- If you want to change the value of the input, you need a attribute value.I rewrite your code like below and when I click the button, the value is changed.

```js
export default class index extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedMarbles: [],
            inputValue: 'Assign',
        };
    }

    handleButtonChange = (e, id) => {
        const { selectedMarbles } = this.state;
        let inputValue;

        let array = [...selectedMarbles]; // make a separate copy of the array
        let index = array.indexOf(id);
        // append that element

        if (index < 0) {
            array.push(id);
            //   e.target.value = 'Unassign';
            inputValue = 'Unassign';
            // e.target.classList.remove('btn-info');
            // e.target.classList.add('btn-danger');
        } else {
            // remove that element
            array.splice(index, 1);
            // e.target.value = 'Assign';
            inputValue = 'Unassign';
            // e.target.classList.add('btn-info');
            // e.target.classList.remove('btn-danger');
        }

        this.setState({ selectedMarbles: array, inputValue });

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    render = () => {
        const { inputValue } = this.state;

        const params = {
            type: 'button',
            className: 'pull-right btn btn-info',
            style: { width: '33%' },
            onClick: e => this.handleButtonChange(e, 1),
            value: inputValue
        };

        return (
            <div className='index'>
                <input {...params } />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You need to know what is [controlled-components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).In your example, you just change the value of the input, but you forget to refresh the view with calling this.setState(). Maybe it is the reason of why the value of input is not changed.

- In your second example, why the value of button changes is that you change the innerHTML of it. If you use value in the button, the value maybe not change too.

Comment: You forgot about changing css btn-info to btn-danger when selected.

Probably there is many (matrix?) input/buttons (array of selected make sens?).

Answer (score 0):

This seams like is a perfect example of abusing react ;) Direct changes in (real) DOM are slow - you're making 3 operations and render (by setState) destroys them.

Why not passing each marble state as prop (stateless functional components) ?

```
const Marble = (props) => {
    const selected = !!props.isSelected
    const params = {
        style: { width: '33%' },
        onClick: e => props.handleClick(e, props.id)
    };
    params.className = selected ? 'pull-right btn btn-danger' : 'pull-right btn btn-info'

    // any kind of element input/button/div/span
    return (
        <div {...params } >
            {selected? 'Selected' : 'Unselected'}
        </div>
    );
}
```

usage (in parent) sth like:

```
<Marble id='someID' isSelected handleClick={this.handleButtonChange} />
```

selectedMarbles has to be an array? maybe object with ids as keys? easier to check state